# Python: Reference the attribute of an object in a list at index[x]

Tags: python, list, dictionary, object, indexing

I’m making a dictionary
and for the keys, I’m tryna use the attribute .name of the objects in the list
when I index an element of the list, I am pointing the the list, and the object inside
how do I point to the list, the object inside, and a single attribute of the object?

```
class test:
 def __init__(self, name):
  self.name = name

list = []

list.append(test('name1'))
list.append(test('name2'))

Dict = {
 list[0].name : value
}
```

'list[0].name' looks terrible and wrong but I'm not sure how to properly reference the name attribute of the object at index[0] in list, I want that key in the dictionary to be 'name1’

Comment: Don't use list as a variable name, it shadows the built-in list. Also I don't see a work around if you just want to reference a *single object* inside the list

Comment: Yes. Yes, this is the way to do it. Do you have any problem with this code besides a subjective "looks terrible"?

Comment: The code above never ran into a problem, I just wrote arbitrary code to try to resemble my problem (my original code was comment heavy and long). I realize now that this made my problem hard to understand. The original error message was telling me that index[1] was out of range (when len(list) == 3), because list[0].name was incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for you?

```
object_list = []
object_list.append(test('name1'))
object_list.append(test('name2'))
Dict = {obj.name: "" for obj in object_list}
```

This will populate an empty dictionary with keys as the name attribute from your objects and value as an empty string, you can set it later as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. I realize the way I posed the question with arbitrary code made it hard to understand my problem, so thanks you for helping out!